# Difference between selectitem and selectitems tags

Tags: java, html, jsp, jsf

What is the difference between the selectitem and selectitems tags in jsf?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference is exactly what you would expect. The `selectitem` tag adds a single item to the HTML list while `selectitems` adds multiple items.

From [JSF Core Tag Reference](http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/help/12-TagReference/core/f_selectItem.html):

#### SelectItem:

The `SelectItem` tag adds a child `UISelectItem` component to the component associated with the enclosing tag. In the HTML renderkit, this creates a single element. It can be used with any of the select tags in the JSF HTML tag library. The body content of this tag must be empty.

*Example:*

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="list1">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="1"></f:selectItem>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

*HTML Output:*

```
<select id="list1" name="list1" size="1">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
</select>
```

#### SelectItems:

The `SelectItems` tag adds a child `UISelectItems` component to the component associated with enclosing tag. You can use this tag to set a list of objects in your domain model as the options for a select component. The body content of this tag must be empty.

*Example:*

```
<h:selectManyListbox id="list">
    <f:selectItems value="#{optionBean.optionList}"></f:selectItem>
</h:selectManyListbox>
```

*HTML Output:*

```
<select id="list" name="list" multiple="true" size="-2147483648">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its also nice to remember that the f:selectItems can point to a SelectItem, an array or Collection of SelectItem objects, or a Map mapping labels to values.