# How to use h:selectOneMenu in f:selectItem?

Tags: jsf

```
    <h:selectOneRadio id="profiles" layout="pageDirection" value="#{bean.selectedProfile}" style="font-size:12px;">

       <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="#{messages.msg_profile1} ">
          <h:selectOneMenu id="countries" value="#{bean.selectedCountry}" required="false"    style="width:190px">
            <f:selectItems value="#{bean.countries}" />
          </h:selectOneMenu>    
        </f:selectItem>

        <f:selectItems value="#{fraudBinPageBean.profiles}"/>    

    </h:selectOneRadio>
```

I have written above code in my app. It is working fine.
But select box displaying above the radio button.
My requirement display the select box beside the radio button.

Can you please help me what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it is working correctly? Referring to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330529/difference-between-selectitem-and-selectitems-tags/330552#330552) it is not possible since the body of the `f:selectItem` tag must be empty.

Try to redesign your form that you get along without the nested `h:selectOneMenu`.

Comment: HI Handy, functionality is working fine. Problem is design. Select box is displaying in above the radio button.

Comment: @venkat: That's interesting. Never tried it but how does the rendered html look like? Could you add it to your question?

Comment: Please see generated view source html code <tr align="left"> <td style="display: inline;" colspan="4"> <select id="form:countries" style="width: 190px;" size="1" name="form:countries"> <option value="0">&lt; no selection &gt;</option> <option value="1">India</option> <option value="2">USA</option> </select> <table id="form:xx" style="font-size: 12px;"> <tbody> <tr> <td> <input id="form:xx:0" type="radio" value="0" name="bin:xx"> <label for="form:xx:0">&nbsp;Profile 1: </label> </td> </tr> </tbody> </table> </td> </tr>

Answer (score 0):

You want to keep your radio button and Select box in same line. This is more related to CSS.

Try This code.

```
    <h:selectOneRadio id="profiles" layout="pageDirection" 
value="#{bean.selectedProfile}" style="font-size:12px;display:inline">
 <f:selectItems value="#{fraudBinPageBean.profiles}"/>  
   </h:selectOneRadio>

    <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="#{messages.msg_profile1} ">
              <h:selectOneMenu id="countries" value="#{bean.selectedCountry}"  required="false"    style="width:190px">
                <f:selectItems value="#{bean.countries}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
```

as shown in above code Add CSS property **Display:inline** to your style attribute of selectoneradio

Comment: Hi Madhu, inline is not working here. Please see generated view source html code  <tr align="left">
<td style="display: inline;" colspan="4">
<select id="form:countries" style="width: 190px;" size="1" name="form:countries">
<option value="0">&lt; no selection &gt;</option>
<option value="1">India</option>
<option value="2">USA</option>
</select>
<table id="form:xx" style="font-size: 12px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<input id="form:xx:0" type="radio" value="0" name="bin:xx">
<label for="form:xx:0">&nbsp;Profile 1: </label>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>

Comment: JSF radio button is taking seperate table.

Comment: @venkat 'Its working fine in IE8 I tested with sample code. Where you have added style(inline) attribute

Comment: I added to radio button. tested in IE6 but not working. <h:selectOneRadio id="profiles" layout="pageDirection" value="#{bean.selectedProfile}" style="font-size:12px;display:inline">