# the selectOneMenu selectItem

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I can't get the selected item from a SelectOneMenu , I filled the selectonemenu by Elements but when I execute the program the display selectoneMenu nothing
the code view is :

```
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{ticketbean.ticket.source}"
                                style="width:201px; height:20px; font-size:10px; font-weight:1px;"
                                required="true">
                                <f:selectItems itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
                                <f:selectItems itemLabel="Logiciel" itemValue="Logiciel" />
                                <f:selectItems itemLabel="Reseaux" itemValue="Reseaux" />
 </h:selectOneMenu>
```

i use jsf and primefrances version 5

Comment: There is also an issue with there being a difference between `<f:selectItem>` and `<f:selectItems>`, and it is more than just the final letter "s."  Use your favorite tag library site to explore the two entirely different tags (mine is http://horstmann.com/corejsf/jsf-tags.html)

Comment: thans youuuu it is workk :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the comments seem to indicate this is the answer, I will offer it as such and add some more explanation, for the benefit of the community.  See also this question and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/330552/241291).

There are a handful of subtleties in JSF that a beginner must pay careful attention to.  One that always trips me up is that core `<f:ajax>` uses `render`, Primefaces `<p:ajax>` uses `update` and earlier versions of Richfaces `<a4j:ajax>` used `rerender`, as the attribute to specify which other elements were the target of the ajax response.  Another good example is `<f:selectItem>` versus `<f:selectItems>`.

This [article](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnask/index.html) goes into the difference fairly well.  The singular variant specifies the label and value of a single selection, and the parent item, such as `<h:selectOneMenu>` or `<h:selectManyCheckbox>` will usually have multiple `<f:selectItem>` children.  Meanwhile the plural variant is bound to a Collection or Map in the backing bean, and within this bean property the values and labels of all choices are specified.  The parent tag usually has only one `<f:selectItems>` child.